# How to add a conditional validator for reactive forms in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have a select with two options:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Access Type</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="accessType">
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="paid-out"> Paid out</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="free"> Free</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

When the user **clicks** "paid", I want to **add a validation**.
But when I **click** "free", I want you to **clear the paid field validation**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use Reactive Forms here. There's a chapter on Reactive Forms in the Angular documentation.  It's an easier way to manage forms.

To get the selected value, you can use `selectionChange`.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" (selectedChange)="onSelectionChange($event)" formControlName="accessType">
    <mat-label>Access Type</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="accessType">
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="paid-out"> Paid out</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="free"> Free</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

(Use `formControlName` if you have a *FormGroup* or `[formControl]` if you only have a *FormControl*).

When the selection changes, a method that I named `onSelectionChange()` is called.
`$event` contains the value you selected. You'll get a `MatSelectChange` object. To get the value you selected, use the `value` property.

```
onSelectionChange(event: MatSelectChange) {
  if (event.value === 'paid-out') {
     myForm.controls.accessType.setValidators(myValidators) 
     myForm.controls.accessType.updateValueAndValidity();
  }    
}
```

When the selected value is `paid-out`, validators will be set on the form control (here your Access Type form control), then the `updateValueAndValidity()` method will be called to update the form control in order to apply validators on it.

To remove validation, call `clearValidators()` method. You'll remove all the validators, so if you have one or multiple validators you don't want to remove, set them after and call `updateValueAndValidity()` method.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I added an event emitted Material **selectionChange**.
Then I added the validations:

- **setValidators**: Set a validator for a control,
- **clearValidators**: Remove the validator from the control,
- **updateValueAndValidity**: Update the value and validation status of the control.

And the result was this:

**template**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Access Type</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="accessType" (selectionChange)="selectedAccessType($event)" >
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="paid-out"> Paid out</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="free"> Free</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('accessType').errors?.required">
          This field is required
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**ts**

```
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder)

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            accessType: [''],
        )}
    }

    selectedAccessType(event: MatSelectChange) {
        switch (event.value) {
            case 'paid-out':
                this.form.get('accessType').setValidators([Validators.required])
                this.form.get('accessType').updateValueAndValidity()
                break
            case 'free':
                this.form.get('accessType').clearValidators()
                this.form.get('accessType').updateValueAndValidity()
                break
            default:
                this.form.get('accessType').clearValidators()
                this.form.get('accessType').updateValueAndValidity()
        }
    }
```